# FirebaseError Exception Email/Password Authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am using Firebase User Authentication, Email/Password method.
I want to test whether i can change my email and i keep getting email invalid when it is correct and when i keep pressing change which is the button to start the change email method i get this.

FirebaseError: There was an exception while performing the request: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)):expected a valid value(number,String,array,object,'true','false' or 'null')

at [Source:org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@3f1bc11e; line:1,column:2]

Can anyone know how to solve this problem ?

```
public class ChangeEmail extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText Password, CurrentEmail, NewEmail;
String FirebaseUserNewEmail, FirebasePassword, FirebaseUserCurrentEmail;
Button buttonDone;
public static final String DEFAULT = "N/A";
String username;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /**
     * Adding our layout to parent class relative layout.
     */
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.changeemail, RelativeLayout);

    CurrentEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CurrentEmail);
    NewEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NewEmail);
    buttonDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDone);
    buttonDone.setOnClickListener(this);
    // Password - Edit Text
    Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
    // Make text style stay the same / as default
    Password.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    // Make password confidential.
    Password.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("project", 0);
    username = prefs.getString("keyusername", DEFAULT);

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ChangeEmail.this);
    username = settings.getString("keyusername", DEFAULT);

    setTitle("Settings");

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void ChangeEmail()
{
    FirebaseUserCurrentEmail = CurrentEmail.getText().toString();
    FirebaseUserNewEmail = NewEmail.getText().toString();
    FirebasePassword = Password.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("Current Email :" + FirebaseUserCurrentEmail);
    System.out.println("New Email :" + FirebaseUserNewEmail);
    System.out.println("Password :" + FirebasePassword);
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://tapamp.firebaseio.com");
    ref.changeEmail(FirebaseUserCurrentEmail, FirebaseUserNewEmail, FirebasePassword, new Firebase.ResultHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome " + FirebaseUserNewEmail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent a = new Intent(ChangeEmail.this, HomePage.class);
            startActivity(a);
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + firebaseError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            switch (firebaseError.getCode()) {
                case FirebaseError.USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST:
                    // handle a non existing user
                    break;
                case FirebaseError.INVALID_PASSWORD:
                    // handle an invalid password
                    break;
                case FirebaseError.INVALID_EMAIL:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Email" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    // handle other errors
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == buttonDone) {
        ChangeEmail();
    }
    else if (view == buttonLogout)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);

        alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.trunk);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Log out"); // your dialog title
        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Intent a = new Intent(ChangeEmail.this, LoginPage.class);
                        a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                        a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        finish();
                        startActivity(a);
                        Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://tapamp.firebaseio.com");
                        ref.unauth();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It is impossible to say what is going wrong, unless you provide us with the minimal code that is necessary to reproduce your problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen will add it !

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen hi, added the code wonder if you can help me to take a look at it? thank you in advance !

Comment: Great. Two questions: can you mark the line that throws the exception? Second: can you replace the `FirebaseUserCurrentEmail`, `FirebaseUserNewEmail` and `FirebasePassword` with hard-coded values and try again? If it still works, update the code in the question. (in case it isn't clear, I'm trying to help you isolate the problem to a specific part of the code.)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen 1st Question : the application is workable. The error that occur is "the email is invalid" when i click on the done button to change the email but when i spam clicking the done button this firebase error occur "FirebaseError: There was an exception while performing the request: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)):expected a valid value(number,String,array,object,'true','false' or 'null')

2nd Question : I can't change email since firebase keep returning "Invalid Email." i try hard-coding the current email , new email and password but the error is occurring.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hey Frank, i found the solution. The parameters given on the website is different from the parameters that is in the code. On the site, the parameters taken in is OldEmail, NewEmail, Password but in the code it is OldEmail, Password, NewEmail. Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: Cool. Great news to hear that you found the problem. Do you mind posting it as an answer and accepting it?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sure thanks alot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters given on the website is different from the parameters that is in the code. On the site, the parameters taken in is OldEmail, NewEmail, Password but in the code it is OldEmail, Password, NewEmail.